# PostgreSQL 9.3 running on Linux - need to authenticate vs. Windows Active Directory

Tags: postgresql-9.3, authentication, active-directory, ldap

- Database server is Ubuntu Linux 3.13.0-68-generic
- Database is PostgreSQL 9.3.10
- LDAP set up according to https://cdc.iseage.org/tutorial-pam-ldap-authentication-active-directory-debianubuntu/
- pg_hba.conf line:
  `host all all 127.0.0.1/32 ldap ldapserver="my.ldap.net" ldapprefix="uid=" ldapsuffix=",ou=People,o=my.net,dc=my,dc=ldap,dc=net"`
- There is a PostgreSQL account set up for searched.user@my.net

I'm able to get successful LDAP searches:

```
~>$ ldapsearch -h my.ldap.net -x -b "ou=People,o=my.net" "uid=searched.user@my.net" cn
```

That returns as expected, the CN of the user looked for. I'm also able to bind lookups as in

```
~>$ ldapsearch -h my.ldap.net -W -D "uid=bind.lookup@my.net" -b "ou=People,o=my.net" "uid=searched.user@my.net" cn
```

and have the correct information returned after the bind.lookup user enters their AD password.

When I try:

```
psql -U "searched.user@my.net"
```

I get prompted for the password. Upon entering the password, I get:

```
psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "searched.user@my.net"
```

That's what I've tried. Any ideas on how I can get this working? I should mention that it is NOT desired to join the database server to the Windows domain - too many other linkage issues would arise.